# PHP Cant read file with special chars

Tags: php, encoding, fread

I'm loading a file by this script:

```
$hFile = fopen($sFile, "r");
$sContent = "";

while(!feof($hFile)) {
    $sContent .= fread($hFile, 4096);
}

fclose($hFile);
```

It works as it should do, but i tried to load a file called `test.txt` 
which contains the following string: `<>863b?)(/&(§&/))!)!=WLKM! K!*ÜQWW!W3³³w2_:LPE`

The variable `$sContent` now doesn't contain anything.

Comment: I try your code and everything was OK. Are you sure about correct printing `$sContent` variable?

Comment: Yes, if I open other files, it works properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8");
```

Do this before writing to the file in the first place.

Comment: i came up using `mb_convert_encoding($sContent, 'UTF-8');`, but thanks!

Comment: @PhilMo Okay! You should either accept my corrected answer or post your own and then accept it so that any future visitors know how to solve the problem.

Comment: without mb_convert_encoding I get instead of: ‘ this: â€˜ and with mb_convert_encoding this: Ã¢Â€Â˜ (my file is UTF8 that I'm reading)